# Identifying and removing rows that don't have a preceding or succeeding year of data ( years where there is no surrounding data)

Tags: r

This may seem trivial and have a trivial answer but its not coming to me:

So I have an example table below:

```
Year    SINDEX
1976    0
1981    16
1982    85
1983    135
1984    141
1986    42
1988    6
1989    0
1990    0
1991    0
1992    0
1994    0
2002    1
2003    3
2004    10
2005    36
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
Year    SINDEX
1981    16
1982    85
1983    135
1984    141
1988    6
1989    0
1990    0
1991    0
1992    0
2002    1
2003    3
2004    10
2005    36
```

having removed the years 1976, 1986 and 1994.

I know how to remove rows its more about how do I find a neat way of identifying these rows of data that don't have any accompanying years of data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first put this data in a dataframe.

```
tmp <- data.frame(matrix(c(1976, 0,
              1981, 16,
              1982, 85,
              1983, 135,
              1984, 141,
              1986, 42,
              1988, 6,
              1989, 0,
              1990, 0,
              1991, 0,
              1992, 0,
              1994, 0,
              2002, 1,
              2003, 3,
              2004, 10,
              2005, 36), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

One solution would be to create two auxiliary variables `aux1` and `aux2`: the first encoding the preceding year and the second encoding the succeeding year:

```
aux1 <- tmp$X1 - 1
aux2 <- tmp$X1 + 1
```

Then you can simply condition on the logical that checks whether or not the preceding or succeeding year is included in the dataset:

```
tmp[aux1 %in% tmp$X1 | aux2 %in% tmp$X1, ]
```

which returns

```
     X1  X2
2  1981  16
3  1982  85
4  1983 135
5  1984 141
7  1988   6
8  1989   0
9  1990   0
10 1991   0
11 1992   0
13 2002   1
14 2003   3
15 2004  10
16 2005  36
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you're already familiar with dplyr (or planning to start using it), here's an alternative approach using the `filter` function and `lead` and `lag`:

```
require(dplyr)
filter(df, Year - lag(Year) == 1L | lead(Year) - Year == 1L)
#   Year SINDEX
#1  1981     16
#2  1982     85
#3  1983    135
#4  1984    141
#5  1988      6
#6  1989      0
#7  1990      0
#8  1991      0
#9  1992      0
#10 2002      1
#11 2003      3
#12 2004     10
#13 2005     36
```

I should note that this approach assumes that the data is already as sorted (as in the example).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely explore this!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data `DF` is sorted by `Year` as in the question, examine successive triples (at ends `partial` lets us look at doubles) and return TRUE if there is at least one difference equal to 1:

```
library(zoo)
DF[ rollapply(DF$Year, 3, function(x) 1 %in% diff(x), partial = TRUE), ]
```

This gives:

```
   Year SINDEX
2  1981     16
3  1982     85
4  1983    135
5  1984    141
7  1988      6
8  1989      0
9  1990      0
10 1991      0
11 1992      0
13 2002      1
14 2003      3
15 2004     10
16 2005     36
```